# Вызвать onclick после onclientclick

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Здравствуйте, как сделать, чтобы после onclientclick срабатывал onclick?

```
            Label labelcount = new Label();
            labelcount.ID = "labelcount";
            labelcount.Text = "";
            Controls.Add(labelcount);
            imImageMicro = ImageButton();
            cbFood = new CheckBox();
            cbFood.AutoPostBack = true;
            cbFood.ID = "CheckBoxFood" + id;
            cbFood.Text = "Food";
            cbFood.Checked = false;
            cbFood.CheckedChanged += cbFood_CheckedChanged;
            bReheat = new Button();

            bReheat.ID = "ReheatButton" + id;
            bReheat.CssClass = "btn btn-info";
            bReheat.Text = "Reheat";
            bReheat.OnClientClick = "javascript: return countclick()";
            bReheat.Click += bReheat_Click;
            Controls.Add(imImageMicro);
            Controls.Add(cbFood);
            Controls.Add(bReheat);


               protected void ScriptSet()
    {


        String script = "";
        script += @"<script>
   window.onload = function () {
        var counter = 0;
        var intervalHandler;

        function count() {
            get('labelcount').innerText = counter;
            counter++;
        }

      function countclick() {
            intervalHandler = setInterval(count, 1000);

            var handler=setTimeout(function () {
                clearInterval(intervalHandler);
                alert('стоп');
            }, 5000);
           return false;
        }


    var get = function (id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

     </script>

            ";

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CountDown", script);


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартная ASP-кнопка и так отправляет PostBack, вызывая серверное событие OnClick. В вашем случае в обработчике клиентского события onclick, Вы возвращаете false, тем самым не позволяете браузеру выполнить стандартную обработку: sumbit (именно так рендерится стандартная ASP'шная серверная кнопка).

Для того, чтобы вызвать серверное событие OnClick через JavaScript, можно симулировать клик: на элементе-кнопке вызвать метод click. Но т.к. у вас уже кнопка имеет обработчик (countclick), то при нажатии он будет выполняться. И здесь можно либо использовать флаг, который будет проверяться в самом начале метода countclick и подниматься после timeout'а. А повторный клик вызывать после поднятия флага, т.е. в том же timeout'е:

```
var isCallPostBack = false;
function countclick() {
    if (isCallPostBack) // Когда флаг будет поднят, выполнится стандартная обработка
                        // Выполнится PostBack от кнопки, а значит сработает серверное событий OnClick
        return true;
    var btn = // Здесь нужно получить DOM-элемент кнопки.
              // Либо через document.getElementById()
              // Либо завести параметр метода
              // Либо через this (только не забыть вызывать с нужным контекстом (call, apply))
    intervalHandler = setInterval(count, 1000);

    var handler=setTimeout(function () {
        clearInterval(intervalHandler);
        alert('стоп');
        // Поднимаем флаг и вызываем клик на кнопке.
        isCallPostBack = true;
        btn.click(); 
    }, 5000);
    return false;
}
```

Либо просто переопределять onclick в timeout'е, и тогда не будет нужны никакие флаги.

Comment: А как можно переписать скрипт, чтобы по окончанию отсчета функция возвращала true ?

Comment: @Nameless вместо *false* напишите *true*. Но, в случае, когда Вам нужно проверить установку таймаута, можете просто использовать условия. Если установилось - вернуть тру, если нет - фолс

Comment: @Nameless, обновил ответ.

Comment: @ nuts119, спасибо Ваш ответ помог мне